# In Mercurial, how to deal with other branches?

Tags: mercurial

Such as I revert to an old revision and I just want to work from this revision. Now I have two heads. How to deal with this situation? Do I need to merge this two heads or just ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options. It is ok to just close the unused head, and leave it as is, Mercurial should not bother you with this anymore.

What I prefer to use is a merge while ignoring one head. You can do this quite easily in TortoiseHg by merging your head to the correct branch and open the option to discard the other revision.

Otherwise, you can follow the steps here:
[Mercurial: Any way to "merge and discard changes"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475634/mercurial-any-way-to-merge-and-discard-changes)